# address not getting passed to a pointer from main to function. C

Tags: c, arrays, pointers

I am trying to read elements in a function and store them in an array in main. I use a pointer to a dynamic array, but its not working. The address i get when i deference the pointer is NULL and the program crashes.

Here is the array :

```
char* first_name = malloc(first_name_length*sizeof(char));
```

Function call from main:

```
get_first_name(fp, first_name_length, first_name);
```

Function declaration:

```
void get_first_name(FILE* fp, int length,char* first);
```

Function definition:

```
void get_first_name(FILE* fp, int length, char* first){

    char c;
    int i = 0;
    int number_of_conversions;

    number_of_conversions = fscanf(fp, "%c", &c);

    while (!isspace(c)){

        first[i] = c;

        number_of_conversions = fscanf(fp, "%c", &c);

        i++;
    }
}
```

Comment: fscanf will not read a white space character, even when using %c.  suggest using int c;  c = fgetc(fp);

Answer (score 0):

something like the following will do the job

```
void get_first_name(FILE* fp, int length, char* first)
{

    int c;
    int i = 0;

    while ( EOF != (c = fgetc(fp) ) && (' ' != c) && (i < (length -1)) )
    {
        first[i] = c;
        i++;
    }
    // terminate the string
    first[i] = '\0';
}
```

Comment: this still crashes the program

Answer (score 0):

1. Open File in read mode

> fp = fopen ( "file.txt", "r"));

2. Make sure file is not Empty.
   using fgetc() will help keeping it simple.

   void get_first_name(FILE* fp, int length, char* first)
   {
     char c;
     int i = 0;
     c=fgetc(fp);

   while (c!=EOF && !isspace(c) ){
           first[i] = c;
           c=fgetc(fp);
           i++;
   }}

3 . If you are using fscanf() for some purpose , you can use **fseek()** for        checking if the file is Empty or not.